# Fetching code from SVN - using a specific revision

Tags: svn

I have a question regarding fetching code from SVN. It will be greatly appreciated if anyone can give me some suggestions for getting this done.

I have following scenario for my application on repository hosting

revision 4 (1 changed file that were changed in revision 3)
revision 3 (1 changed file)
revision 2 (1 file added)

I want to get a working copy that includes all changes from revision 2 to Head but does NOT include the changes for revisions 3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you?

```
svn merge <repository_location> . -c -3
```

But also be cautious, think about the following situation:

```
revision2: you change some text
revision3: you add some text
revision4: you change the text added in revision3
```

If you want the changes from 2 and 4, but not 3 then you have a problem. Because in that situation revision 4 has no clue about the additions made in revision 3. This is also a common problem when branching/merging when you merge a range of revision, but you forget to merge a couple of revisions from your branch. They will be simply gone after merging back to your trunk. But I'm drifting off now...

Comment: I am getting file conflicts here and file contains data up to last revision. Is there any way exist for getting my scenario?"

Comment: @Rup I think the best thing you can do is manually compare revisions 2 and 4 and decide what you need and what to remove...